# Как сохранять в файлы текст на русском языке в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Как сохранять в файлы текст на русском языке в Python?
Когда я включаю этот код:
'''
open("file.txt", "w").write("привет мир")
'''
получаю ошибку:

```
    open("file.txt", "w").write("привет мир")
  File "C:\Users\Elena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Попробуйте указать кодировку в `open` через параметр `encoding="utf-8"`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Попробуй открыть файл с использованием кодеков

```
import codecs
writefile = codecs.open('write.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать with:

```
file = "FILE_PATH"

with open(file, mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write("Привет")
```

Comment: Можно, но `with` только автоматически закрывает файл, а это не связано с проблемой автора вопроса

Comment: Можно попробовать явно прописать кодировку:
open('test.txt','w', encoding='utf-8')

Comment: Спасибо! кодировка помогла!!!

Comment: @AhmedAyman123, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)